# How to use Unique Composite Key

Tags: database, database-design

I have a table

```
Item(ItemName*, ItemSize*, Price, Notes)
```

I was making composite key of (ItemName,ItemSize) to uniquely identify item. And now after reading some answers on stackoverflow suggesting the use of UNIQUE i revised it as

```
Item(ItemID*, ItemName, ItemSize, Price, Notes)
```

But How to apply UNIQUE constraint on ItemName and ItemSize

*please correct if there is something wrong in question*

Comment: What meaning are you trying to convey, with the asterisks ?

Comment: I think the use as a primary key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Items ADD UNIQUE INDEX(ItemName, ItemSize);
```

and [here's an article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLUnique.aspx) explaining how to achieve the same using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, i am not asking for code. Please explain it in words. I am designing Database in SQL server 2005.

Comment: The idea is to add unique index (or unique constraint which is the same) on those two columns.

Comment: How will i do the same graphically in SQL server?

Comment: What do you mean by graphically? SQL is a scripting language. Are you using some tool to create and manage your databases? If yes then the answer will depend on the graphical tool you are using. If you are using SQL Server Management studio here's how you could define constraints: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLUnique.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was using Microsoft SQL server Management Studio Express

Comment: Well then checkout the article.

Comment: Don't use the unique index syntax. Use a unique *constraint*. The difference can be important.

Comment: No, it is not the same. It is a GUID column.

Comment: @dportas: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/26/sql-server-difference-between-unique-index-vs-unique-constraint/

Comment: In principle a constraint is part of the logical level of the database whereas an index is a physical implementation of the database. Keys are properly a logical feature rather than a physical one. Constraints are part of standard SQL whereas indexes are not. Most users of the database will expect keys to implemented as constraints rather than just indexes and if you use the index syntax they may miss the fact that the key exists at all. Also many development and DB management tools may recognise constraints as keys but not indexes. Also, constraints are in the info-schema. Indexes are not.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE Items ADD CONSTRAINT uc_name_size UNIQUE (ItemName,ItemSize)
```

reference from [oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php) and [postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html) doc

Answer (score 1):

1. You are getting hung up on One Tool to do a task.  WIthout understanding that:

   - as Darin states, at the end of the day, SQL is a character-based language
   - any and all commands (Data Manipualtion, or Data Definition as in this case), are executed on the SQL server as character strings
   - there are over one hundred GUI SQL Server Administration tools, from the rubbish that MS keeps churning out every other year, to mature products that keep growing (not replaced or rewritten)
   - you can click or drag or whatever in whatever GUI you use, but when you hit the "save" or "apply" button, the all do the same thing: send an SQL character string to the SQL server for processing

   Therefore yes, you do need to understand what is happening at the SQL command level if you are going to either adinister the server or model/implement databases.  Otherwise you will do unintended things when you click or drag.
2. SQL has been around for over 30 years, and it has come a long way (it is still very limited, but that is not relevant here).  In the old days, we only had
   `{DROP|CREATE} [UNIQUE] [CLUSTERED] INDEX name ON table (columns, ...)`
   syntax. As it expanded, more Relational constructs were added, and we have the
   `ALTER TABLE table {ADD|DROP} {UNIQUE|PRIMARY KEY} CONSTRAINT name (columns,...)`
   syntax.

   Dave Pinal is correct to a point: in terms of data storage structures inside the server ,both `INDEX` and `CONSTRAINT` syntaxes result in the same thing, an index.

   But he is just answering a question, and obviously has not heard about the ISO/IEC/ANSI Standard SQL characterististics that are implied in the newer `CONSTRAINT` syntax, which are not implied in the `INDEX` syntax (if you use it, you have to specify those parameters explicitly). More important, there are many parameters that can be supplied in the `INDEX` syntax which are absent in the `CONSTRAINT` syntax.  So there are significant differences, which may not be relevant to small servers running in a default state.

   Generally people who are inclined towards performance at the physical level, or who have hundreds of tables to administer, use the `INDEX` syntax; amd people who distance themselves from the physical us the `CONSTRAINT`.

   - The point is, use one XOR the other, do not use a combination: that leads to creating duplicate indices that you are not even aware of (because they do not show up in the broken MS GUI panel that you are looking at).
     .

   Dave confuses things: there is no such thing as a "Primary Key index". It is **either** a Primary Key Constraint **or** a Index (which may be the Primary Key, and have setting relevant to supporting a PK)..
3. The next thing that will confuse anyone, beginner or otherwise, is that you are used to seeing all kinds of funny drawings that are supposed to depict dat or data models, and they do not.  MS is the worst offender, in each different product, there is quite a different funny diagram and set of symbols.  There is no commonality or standard; there are symbols that depict importaant aspect of the design, in one picture that you may want in another picture, and you can't get it.

   Well, actually there is a Relational Database Modelling Standard, called IDEF1X.  But MS have not heard of it.  The idea is with a standard, **all** teh important information regarding the model; the subtleties; etc, are identified in the single model.  Many different teams can use the single model.  And of course it has its standard set of symbols and notation.

   - Point is, learn the standards, it will clear up a lot of confusion for you.  Then, regardless of what GUI tool you have on your screen today, you will know what you clearly want/have in your data model, and what is going on inside the server.
   - Point is, re "how do I do this graphically", you do it in any diagramming tool, because you own the model, and you set choose the settings on the tables.  No MS GUI has ever, or will ever give that to you.
     .

   The GUI is not a substitute for knowledge.
4. Could you explain: if as you state, `(ItemName, ItemSize)` forms an unique key on that particular table, on what basis do you think you need instead `(ItemName, ItemSize`, plus anything more `)`? How can you get more unique than unique ?

Comment: Each item is different from each other, some items may have same name but have different sizes therefore combination of both is unique.

Comment: I am a student, i am familiar with language but GUI makes it easy. Surely i must also learn the syntax and i am learning. For my problem i am using the solution suggested by Darin.

Comment: @LifeH2O. No problem. Leave `(ItemName, ItemSize)` as it is.

Comment: To 4: He is trying to switch from (ItemName, ItemSize) as PRIMARY KEY to only ItemID, and then have a composite UNIQUE KEY on (ItemName, ItemSize) to assure that that combination is not duplicated.