# Laravel - efficient way to check database parameters before insert

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have populate a form of which every text field generated is based on the database result. I simply name every text field using the `id`. Now when the form is filled, I use controller to save it. But prior to insert the database, I loop the `Request::input()` to check every item whether such entry is exist or not. I just wonder if there is **efficient way** to check every item in the loop to insert it into db. Here is my code

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, $inid)
{       
    $startOfDay = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
    $endOfDay = Carbon::now()->endOfDay();

    $instruments = InstrumentReading::whereBetween('created_at', [$startOfDay, $endOfDay])
                                    ->where('iv_inid', '=', $inid)
                                    ->get();
    foreach ($request->input() as $k => $v) {
        $read = new InstrumentReading;
        $read->iv_inid = $inid;
        $read->iv_ipid = $k;
        $read->iv_usid = Auth::user()->id;
        $read->iv_reading = $v;
        $read->save();
    }
    if ($instruments->count() > 0) {            
        //to filter the iv_ipid...
        foreach($instruments as $instrument)
        {
            $instrument->iv_status = "VOID";
            $instrument->save();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Set your $fillable property in your InstrumentReading model with your actual column name. Then set the form inputs name to the same name that your columns have. Simply do $read->fill($request->all())->save();.

Comment: i don't get it how $fillable will solve the above problem. As you can see, the text field's name is based on an id of some row in db. So what i did is to loop every text field as a new entry to InstrumentReading. But before that, I need to check whether the entry is exist or not by checking 3 parameters first.

Comment: Why your `$check` contains `->where('created_at', Carbon::now())`? It will always be `!$check->count()` in this case. Also `new InstrumentReading::where` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i suppose to check `created_at` for date only not the time. It's my mistake by the way

Comment: First of all, remove the `->where('created_at', Carbon::now())`

Comment: do you wish to remain DB agnostic? and if not, what DB are you using? 
(as a DBA, I hate DBA agnostic code in stuff like this because you skip a ton of DB vendor specific enhancements)

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul the title need a bit fixing Laravel - efficient way to check database `parameters` before insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In words of efficent approach what you can do is to simple check / fetch **ONLY** all posible rows from the database, and the check in the loop if the row was already inserted. Also fetch only `iv_ipid` column, as we do not need all columns from the table to do our check. It will be faster to select only the column we need. You can use directly `Fluent` ([Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries)) over `Eloquent` to pull the data from database as it greatly increase the performance for a simple query like this.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, $inid)
{
    // Search only records with submitted iv_ipid, iv_inid and created today
    $alreadyInserted = DB::table('instrument_readings')
                   ->whereBetween('created_at', [
                       Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), 
                       Carbon::now()->endOfDay()
                   ])
                   // Get only records with submitted iv_ipid
                   ->whereIn('iv_ipid', array_keys($request->input()))
                   // Get records with given iv_inid only
                   ->where('iv_inid', $inid)
                   // For our check we need only one column, 
                   // no need to select all of them, it will be fast
                   ->select('iv_ipid')
                   // Get the records from DB
                   ->lists('iv_ipid');

    foreach ($request->input() as $k => $v) {
        // Very simple check if iv_ipid is not in the array
        // it does not exists in the database
        if (!in_array($k, $alreadyInserted)) {
            $read = new InstrumentReading;
            $read->iv_inid = $inid;
            $read->iv_ipid = $k;
            $read->iv_usid = Auth::user()->id;
            $read->iv_reading = $v;
            $read->save();
        } else {
            //todo
        }
}
```

This is the most efficent way suggested until now, because you fetch at once only the records you are interested in, not all records from today. Also you fetch only one column, the one that we need for out check. `Eloquent` ususlally give a lot of overheat on the perfomance, so in the suggested code I use directly `Fluent`, which will boost the speed this part of code is executed by ~ 20%.

Your mistake in the original code is that you are doing database call each time in a loop. When you need such a simple task as a check, **never** put database calls, queries etc. in a loop. It is an overkill. Instead select all needed data before the loop and then do your checks.

Now this is in case you only need to save new records to database. In case you want to manipulate each record in the loop, let's say you need to loop through each submited entry, get get the model or create it if it does not exists and then do something else with this model, the most efficent way then will be this one:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, $inid)
{
    foreach ($request->input() as $k => $v) {
       // Here you search for match with given attributes
       // If object in DB with this attributes exists
       // It will be returned, otherwise new one will be constructed
       // But yet not saved in DB
       $model = InstrumentReading::firstOrNew([
           'iv_inid' => $inid,
           'iv_ipid' => $k,
           'iv_usid' => Auth::user()->id
       ]);

       // Check if it is existing DB row or a new instance
       if (!$model->exists()) {
           // If it is a new one set $v and save
           $model->iv_reading = $v;
           $model->save();
       }

    // Do something with the model here
    .....   
}
```

This way Laravel will check if model with the passed parameters already exist in database, and if so it will return it for you. If it does not exist, it will create new instance of it, so you can then set the `$v` and save to db. So you are good to go to do anything else with this model and you can be sure it exists in database after this point.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will send request to database every time you need to check the value. Instead, search all value of this day then check the value. This approach will send request to database only one time.

```
$startOfDay = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$endOfDay = Carbon::now()->endOfDay();

// Search only this day
$instruments = InstrumentReading::whereBetween('created_at', [$startOfDay, $endOfDay])->get();

foreach($instruments as $instrument)
{
    // Check the value
}
```

Comment: is it within the `controller`?

Comment: Basically you can put it anywhere. It depends how you structured your application. But, to be clear, I was updated the code to controller.

Comment: -1. Selecting all rows from current date can not be perfomance wise. He needs only the records with the current submitted params. Also `Eloquent` is slower than `Fluent` and he does not need all columns from the table, which is additional overheat.

Comment: @shaddy you should read the comment. He want to find by date only which means on that day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387563/laravel-efficient-way-to-check-database-paramters-before-insert/30449416#comment48979510_30387563

Comment: @mul14 Yes, he needs to find all records from today, that have the submitted `iv_inid` and `iv_ipid`, there is no point to select all not needed records.

Comment: @shaddy read the `// todo something else with $check`. I thought he want to do something else if the input already exists on database. If not, he should not put `else` in his code.

Comment: @mul14 i have update the working code, but just like @shaddy said, i still need to filter out the `iv_ipid`

Answer (score 1):

#### First approach (efficiency first)

Consider using a simple SQL `INSERT IGNORE` Query and use [Fluent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries), i.e.:

- Make a composite unique key containing:

  1. `iv_inid`
  2. `iv_ipid`
  3. `created_time`, up to an hour granularity, this is important, because `created_at` might have a far greater granularity than your intended purpose, and might slow things down a bit.
- Use `DB`, i.e.:

> DB::query(
>       "INSERT IGNORE INTO $yourTable VALUES ( ... )"
>   );

Pros:
- Extremely fast, all the necessary checking is done on the DB Server

Cons:
- You cannot know which values triggered a duplicate value / unique key violation, as related errors are treated as warnings.

#### Second approach (convenience first)

Use [firstOrFail](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrFail), i.e.:

```
$startOfDay = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$endOfDay = Carbon::now()->endOfDay();

// ... for

try {
    InstrumentReading::where('iv_inid', $inid)
        ->where('iv_ipid', $k)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startOfDay, $endOfDay])
        ->firstOrFail();

    continue;
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    $instrumentReading = InstrumentReading::create([
        // your values
    ]);
}

// ... endfor
```

Pros:
- Easy to implement

Cons:
- Somewhat slower than simple queries

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to say composite key, just multiple columns `UNIQUE KEY`.  Check the answer on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699125/how-to-use-unique-composite-key) for further reading